# Missing email attachments

Tags: safari, gmail, email, attachments

I have a Gmail account but access all my email through Apple Mail. I noticed in the last month or so that I'm not seeing the attachments that are being sent to me. In order to access the attachments, I have to open up Gmail through Safari. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You should provide a screenshot of the `Mail.app` interface, and of a message that should have an attachment.

Comment: What do you mean by "not seeing the attachments"?. Do you not see their previews, or do you not see any indication of them at all - which leaves you to take notice of them from the context of the mail.

Comment: No I don't see any indication of the attachments except for the content of the email alluding to the attachment.

Comment: Screenshots! Bonus points for the same message in the gmail (web) interface.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with another IMAP server. I'm pretty sure it is a bug in Mail.app. I also have attachments disappearing, when I move a message from one folder to another. On server side the attachement is correctly moved with the attachment. I believe there is nothing you can do but wait for Apple to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that these selections are checked? Having the incorrect option selected can produce the very symptoms you're describing.

[image]

[image]